# How to make hibernate reverse engineering keep exactly same object field names as database table column names?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm running into an issue with Hibernate reverse engineering my postgres database. When hibernate encounters a column, which has a `_` character (like `mycolumn_gb`) it removes the underscore, and capitalizes the next subsequent character: `mycolumnGb`.

How can I force Hibernate to avoid any such alterations?

Answer (score 0):

1) Create sub class of `DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy`, overriding `columnToPropertyName` method.

```
package com.example;

import org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy;
import org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.ReverseEngineeringStrategy;
import org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.TableIdentifier;

public class SampleReverseEngineeringStrategy extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy {

    public SampleReverseEngineeringStrategy(ReverseEngineeringStrategy delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public String columnToPropertyName(TableIdentifier table, String column) {
        return column;
    }
}
```

2) Set to `reveng. strategy`.

[image]

refs:

- [6.3. Custom strategy - Hibernate Tools Reference Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#custom-reveng-strategy)